# Would this partitioning scheme work for penta-boot system?

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

I'd like to have many operating systems on one HD in my laptop.  Booting from USB is not an option; I have to boot from the HD.

**Is the following partition scheme sensible?**

**What should I do for swap partitions?**

4 primary partitions containing

- Recovery stuff
- Windows 7
- Linux (eg Fedora)
- EXTENDED partition containing

  - logical drive with Linux (eg Sabyon)
  - logical drive with Linux (eg Mageia)
  - logical drive with /home

This would all be on one hard drive.  I understand that there's a 2 TiB limit; the drive is 500 GB so that's okay. I understand that I'd need a boot loader to boot the OSs in the extended partition's logical drives.  I plan to use maybe GAG or Smart Boot Manager.  (*I know software suggestions are strongly discouraged, but I'd welcome suggestions for FOSS boot loaders in the comments*)

EDIT: This question is about the particular situation of wanting to have more that 4 bootable OSs on one drive.  The user can only have 4 primary partitions with a bootable OS in each.  What does a user do if more partitions are needed?  Can an OS be booted from a logical drive in an extended partition?

Comment: This just feels like a bad idea, especially on a laptop.  I see no particular reason it wouldn't WORK, though.  (Assuming all these bits play nice with logical partitions.)  I think you're just asking for trouble, though.

Comment: Whhhhhyyyyyyyyy

Comment: @DanBeale - Just excessive complexity.  Something's likely to get screwed up, somewhere, and it might not be easy to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Skip trying to mess around with logcal drives in your MBR partition, and use [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) for all of your linux filesystems.

- Recovery stuff
- Windows 7
- shared /boot
- LVM - Volume group - create the group, and create small LVs, add space to LVs when required.

  - shared /home so you have access to your data everywhere.
  - logical volume {1..n} the root fs for as many linux distros as you want.